# Listing Firebase Storage objects omits all metadata

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I've been trying to get a list of all files in a specific folder of my storage bucket and it works pretty well but there is no information about the meta of the object as described in this document: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects#resource

The shape of the item object is not the same and instead gives a "ReferenceCompat" for each item in the array.

Instead - the only provided properties are bucket, fullPath and name.

Does anyone know why this is?

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/list-files

```
  const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(folder);
  const listFiles = function listFilesAndSaveToSlice() {
    storageRef
      .listAll()
      .then((res) => {
        res.items.forEach((item) => {
           let {name, id, owner, acl, ...etc} = item;
           // {name: name, id: undefined, ...undefined}
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {

      });
  };
```

This is the object provided instead of what's expected:

```
ReferenceCompat: {
    "_delegate": {
        "_service": {
            "app": {
                "name": "[DEFAULT]",
                "automaticDataCollectionEnabled": false,
                "options": {
                    "apiKey": "xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx",
                    "authDomain": "xxxxxx",
                    "projectId": "xxxx",
                    "storageBucket": "xxxxxx",
                    "messagingSenderId": "xxxxxxxxx",
                    "appId": "xxxxxxxx"
                }
            },
            "_authProvider": {
                "name": "auth-internal",
                "container": {
                    "name": "[DEFAULT]",
                    "providers": {}
                },
                "component": {
                    "name": "auth-internal",
                    "multipleInstances": false,
                    "instantiationMode": "LAZY",
                    "type": "PRIVATE"
                },
                "instances": {},
                "instancesDeferred": {},
                "onInitCallbacks": {}
            },
            "_appCheckProvider": {
                "name": "app-check-internal",
                "container": {
                    "name": "[DEFAULT]",
                    "providers": {}
                },
                "component": null,
                "instances": {},
                "instancesDeferred": {},
                "onInitCallbacks": {}
            },
            "_pool": {},
            "_firebaseVersion": "8.6.5",
            "_bucket": {
                "bucket": "xxxxx",
                "path_": ""
            },
            "_host": "firebasestorage.googleapis.com",
            "_appId": null,
            "_deleted": false,
            "_maxOperationRetryTime": 120000,
            "_maxUploadRetryTime": 600000,
            "_requests": {}
        },
        "_location": {
            "bucket": "xxxxxxxxxx",
            "path_": "samples/coming to an end v2.mp3.asd"
        }
    },
    "storage": {
        "app": {
            "name": "[DEFAULT]",
            "automaticDataCollectionEnabled": false,
            "options": {
                "apiKey": "xxxxxx",
                "authDomain": "xxxxxx",
                "projectId": "xxxxx",
                "storageBucket": "xxxxx",
                "messagingSenderId": "xxxxx",
                "appId": "xxxx"
            }
        },
        "_delegate": {
            "app": {
                "name": "[DEFAULT]",
                "automaticDataCollectionEnabled": false,
                "options": {
                    "apiKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "authDomain": "xxxxxxx",
                    "projectId": "xxxxxx",
                    "storageBucket": "xxxxx",
                    "messagingSenderId": "xxxxx",
                    "appId": "xxxxxx"
                }
            },
            "_authProvider": {
                "name": "auth-internal",
                "container": {
                    "name": "[DEFAULT]",
                    "providers": {}
                },
                "component": {
                    "name": "auth-internal",
                    "multipleInstances": false,
                    "instantiationMode": "LAZY",
                    "type": "PRIVATE"
                },
                "instances": {},
                "instancesDeferred": {},
                "onInitCallbacks": {}
            },
            "_appCheckProvider": {
                "name": "app-check-internal",
                "container": {
                    "name": "[DEFAULT]",
                    "providers": {}
                },
                "component": null,
                "instances": {},
                "instancesDeferred": {},
                "onInitCallbacks": {}
            },
            "_pool": {},
            "_firebaseVersion": "8.6.5",
            "_bucket": {
                "bucket": "megatech-ltd.appspot.com",
                "path_": ""
            },
            "_host": "firebasestorage.googleapis.com",
            "_appId": null,
            "_deleted": false,
            "_maxOperationRetryTime": 120000,
            "_maxUploadRetryTime": 600000,
            "_requests": {}
        },
        "INTERNAL": {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you `console.log(item)` inside the loop, and include the updated code and its output in the question?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I added an instance of the object in the description - thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the firebase storage api docs, `list()` returns a [`ListResult`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.ListResult) which in turn may contain multiple [`Reference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference) objects.

If you want to fetch the metadata for all of the objects returned by `list()`, you'll need to call [`Reference.getMetadata()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#getmetadata) on each individual file returned.